# Android HttpURLConnection POST gives HTTP error 411

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-networking

I'm having problems with POST request and when running on emulator.

Problem with device:
When sending POST request I am getting this 411 error (Content-Length required). Adding that request property doesn't help.

Problem with emulator:
When typing REST url to web client, it works. But when running it with the application client, I get UnkownHostExpection.

This far I am pretty clueless what to be done to fix my issues, so I was hoping you could point out some tips to solve these.

Thanks.

Here is relevant code:

```
    URL url = new URL("http://etc..");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", CHARSET_UTF8);

    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
    conn.getOutputStream().write(myPostParams.getBytes(CHARSET_UTF8));

    conn.connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting to use setFixedLengthStreamingMode() instead of setChunkedStreamingMode(0)?

Comment: The problem most likely is with the server having some very old configs and that's why not working with android devices. I did try all possible ways to deal with it.

Comment: Was this ever resolved to be a Apache error? I can't seem to get chunking to work on my server.

Answer (score 0):

This "`setFixedLengthStreamingMode()`" is working for me